# AppArmor rule that allows access to any file in home directory via a particular symbolic link

Tags: linux, symlink, apparmor

The following AppArmor profile allows the program `myprog` to read the user's configuration file found at `~/.myprogrc`.

```
abi <abi/3.0>,

include <tunables/global>

profile myprog /usr/bin/myprog {
    include <abstractions/base>
    owner @{HOME}/.myprogrc r,
}
```

If the user has made `~/.myprogrc` a symbolic link to the actual configuration file (e.g. `ln -s ~/Documents/myprog-config ~/.myprogrc`), then AppArmor would deny `myprog` access to the file that the `~/.myprogrc` symbolic link points to. How do I write an AppArmor rule such that `myprog` would be able to read any file in the user's home directory that the `~/.myprogrc` symlink points to?

(AppArmor version 3.0.8, OS: Debian 12)